# How to make li change colors (or add effects when hovered)

Tags: html, css, web

I need help with making both the 'a' and 'ion-icon' change color whenever li is hovered over.

```
<nav class="menu-options open">
            <ul class="mobile-nav-list">
              <li class="mvl-home">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-nav-link">Home</a>
                <ion-icon class="mobile-nav-icons" name="home"></ion-icon>
              </li>
              <li class="mvl-flipper">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-nav-link mvl-flipper">Flipper</a>
                <ion-icon class="mobile-nav-icons" name="person"></ion-icon>
              </li>
              <li class="mvl-seller">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-nav-link">Seller</a>
                <ion-icon class="mobile-nav-icons" name="cash"></ion-icon>
              </li>
              <li class="mvl-login">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-nav-link">Login</a>
                <ion-icon class="mobile-nav-icons" name="log-in"></ion-icon>
              </li>
              <li class="mvl-signup">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-nav-link">Signup</a>
                <ion-icon
                  class="mobile-nav-icons"
                  name="arrow-up-circle"
                ></ion-icon>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.mobile-nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.mobile-nav-list li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(156, 156, 156, 0.3);
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  margin: 1rem 1.2rem;
}

.mobile-nav-list li a {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
}

.mobile-nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  display: inline-block;
}
.mobile-nav-icons {
  color: #9c9c9c;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

/* Mobile options different hover colors */

.mvl-home:hover,
.mvl-home:active,
.mvl-login:hover,
.mvl-login:active,
.mvl-signup:hover,
.mvl-signup:active {
  color: #fff;
}
```

I tried putting "mvl-home" as class for the anchor and ion-icon but one or the other would not change color when hovered over (ex: I hovered over home which would change color but the home icon would not change colors).

I am expecting for both the anchor elements and ion-icon to change colors when hovered over the li element.

Again, I don't have the ion-icon inside the anchor so I could use flex space-between to spread the text and icon apart from each other.

Comment: You can remove the `:active` for the hover effect because the `:hover` carries over the styles to the `:active` automatically.